Kwork drains the battery
Completely modifying my question as I've figured out where the power consumption is coming from
Ubuntu is draining the battery really fast, apparently due to something called "Kwork":
Summary: 2332.8 wakeups/second,  0.0 GPU ops/seconds, 0.0 VFS ops/sec and 2450.4

                Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
            24227 ms/s       4.2        kWork          acpi_os_execute_deferred
              4.8 ms/s     656.0        Timer          tick_nohz_handler
             15.2 ms/s     279.4        Process        [PID 6400] /app/brave/bra
             11.3 ms/s     207.4        Interrupt      [7] sched(softirq)
              2.4 ms/s     123.8        Interrupt      [6] AMDI0010:03
              4.4 ms/s     107.0        Process        [PID 3013] /usr/lib/xorg/
              4.6 ms/s      87.0        Interrupt      [77] amdgpu
              1.2 ms/s      86.6        Process        [PID 948] [irq/76-rtw89_p
              4.6 ms/s      74.7        Interrupt      [3] net_rx(softirq)
              7.8 ms/s      65.9        Process        [PID 3307] /usr/bin/gnome
             11.1 ms/s      63.0        Process        [PID 4251] /app/brave/bra
              3.3 ms/s      53.8        Process        [PID 4580] /app/brave/bra
              6.1 ms/s      52.4        Process        [PID 4491] /app/brave/bra
              1.3 ms/s      38.0        Process        [PID 4576] /app/brave/bra
              1.3 ms/s      29.7        Process        [PID 4471] /app/brave/bra
            314.6 µs/s      29.2        Process        [PID 17] [rcu_preempt]
              1.9 ms/s      23.8        Process        [PID 3603] /usr/libexec/i

Thoughts on how to proceed to debug? Interestingly enough, when on AC power, KWork is all the way down in power usage.
Here are the interrupts when running grep . -r /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/, I get:
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1F:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe13:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe0F:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe03:       0     STS invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1D:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/ff_pwr_btn:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe11:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe0D:       0         disabled     unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe01:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/ff_rt_clk:       0         disabled     unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/ff_pmtimer:       0     STS invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1B:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe0B:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe18:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe08:       0         disabled     unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/error:       0
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe16:       0     STS invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/sci:   56257
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe06:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe14:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe04:       0  EN     enabled      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1E:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe12:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe0E:       0         disabled     unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe02:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1C:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe10:       0  EN     enabled      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe0C:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe00:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe_all:   56257
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe19:       0         disabled     unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1A:       0         disabled     unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe09:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe0A:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe17:   56257  EN     enabled      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/ff_gbl_lock:       0  EN     enabled      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe07:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/sci_not:       0
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe15:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe05:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/ff_slp_btn:       0         invalid      unmasked

ChatGPT suggested me to check the contents of dmesg | grep -i error :
[    0.576154] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
[    5.978388] ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: error -ETIMEDOUT: PPM init failed

Also, the contents of dmesg | tail -n 50 :
[    5.978380] ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: failed to reset PPM!
[    5.978388] ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: error -ETIMEDOUT: PPM init failed
[    6.552774] rfkill: input handler disabled
[    6.707445] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[    8.774245] wlo1: authenticate with 98:52:4a:4b:c5:59 (local address=94:bb:43:26:56:e8)
[    8.774254] wlo1: send auth to 98:52:4a:4b:c5:59 (try 1/3)
[    8.775342] wlo1: authenticated
[    8.777395] wlo1: associate with 98:52:4a:4b:c5:59 (try 1/3)
[    8.780430] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 98:52:4a:4b:c5:59 (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=2)
[    8.890917] wlo1: associated
[    8.890949] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 98:52:4a:4b:c5:59
[    9.667528] rfkill: input handler enabled
[   10.110709] kauditd_printk_skb: 131 callbacks suppressed
[   10.110713] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738854.105:142): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="mknod" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.db" pid=2386 comm="Xorg" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   10.110804] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738854.105:143): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.db" pid=2386 comm="Xorg" requested_mask="rc" denied_mask="rc" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   10.110811] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738854.105:144): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.db" pid=2386 comm="Xorg" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   10.110816] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738854.105:145): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="mknod" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.idx" pid=2386 comm="Xorg" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   10.110819] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738854.105:146): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.idx" pid=2386 comm="Xorg" requested_mask="rc" denied_mask="rc" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   10.110823] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738854.105:147): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.idx" pid=2386 comm="Xorg" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   10.110826] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738854.105:148): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_lock" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.db" pid=2386 comm="Xorg" requested_mask="wk" denied_mask="wk" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   10.110829] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738854.105:149): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_lock" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.idx" pid=2386 comm="Xorg" requested_mask="wk" denied_mask="wk" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   10.110833] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738854.105:150): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.db" pid=2386 comm="Xorg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   10.111069] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738854.105:151): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.idx" pid=2386 comm="Xorg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   10.776074] NFSD: Using nfsdcld client tracking operations.
[   10.776079] NFSD: no clients to reclaim, skipping NFSv4 grace period (net f0000000)
[   11.707635] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[   11.825880] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   14.391898] warning: `ThreadPoolForeg' uses wireless extensions which will stop working for Wi-Fi 7 hardware; use nl80211
[   64.526643] kauditd_printk_skb: 1176 callbacks suppressed
[   64.526648] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738909.016:1328): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_lock" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.db" pid=2386 comm="Xorg:sh0" requested_mask="wk" denied_mask="wk" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   64.526653] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738909.016:1329): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_lock" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.idx" pid=2386 comm="Xorg:sh0" requested_mask="wk" denied_mask="wk" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   64.526664] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738909.016:1330): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.db" pid=2386 comm="Xorg:sh0" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   64.526677] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738909.016:1331): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.idx" pid=2386 comm="Xorg:sh0" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   64.526707] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738909.016:1332): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.idx" pid=2386 comm="Xorg:sh0" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   64.526718] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738909.016:1333): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.idx" pid=2386 comm="Xorg:sh0" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   64.526727] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738909.016:1334): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.idx" pid=2386 comm="Xorg:sh0" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   64.526737] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738909.016:1335): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.db" pid=2386 comm="Xorg:sh0" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   64.526750] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738909.016:1336): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.idx" pid=2386 comm="Xorg:sh0" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   64.526767] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738909.016:1337): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.idx" pid=2386 comm="Xorg:sh0" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   77.960428] kauditd_printk_skb: 214 callbacks suppressed
[   77.960433] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738922.271:1552): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_lock" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.db" pid=2386 comm="Xorg" requested_mask="wk" denied_mask="wk" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   77.960439] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738922.271:1553): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_lock" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.idx" pid=2386 comm="Xorg" requested_mask="wk" denied_mask="wk" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   77.960442] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738922.271:1554): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.db" pid=2386 comm="Xorg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   77.960451] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738922.271:1555): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.idx" pid=2386 comm="Xorg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   77.960470] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738922.271:1556): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.idx" pid=2386 comm="Xorg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   77.960477] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738922.271:1557): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.idx" pid=2386 comm="Xorg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   77.960479] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738922.271:1558): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.idx" pid=2386 comm="Xorg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   77.960488] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738922.271:1559): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.db" pid=2386 comm="Xorg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   77.960496] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738922.271:1560): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.idx" pid=2386 comm="Xorg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   77.960503] audit: type=1400 audit(1728738922.271:1561): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" class="file" profile="Xorg" name="/home/evan/.cache/mesa_shader_cache_db/part0/mesa_cache.idx" pid=2386 comm="Xorg" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000

Also note that no matter if on AC Power or Battery power, one of my CPU threads is always running around 98%. Also note that I am on powersave governor.

You've not posted any info about which process maxes out that CPU thread.

You can not compare power consumption between 2 different operating systems: we use different tools with different demands. "Here are the details of my hardware:" that is not important. What you need to check is top and active services you can disable. also check the governor you use: performance mode uses all it can.

I've modified my post with the power consumption details: the culprit is kWork

The acpi_os_execute_deferred in the description of kWork might be a clue about the cause. The answer in kworker eating 85% CPU 1 most of the time! might help.

@ChesterGillon Thanks! I added the contents of grep . -r /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/ to my post. How do you think I should proceed fromt here? I'm not a pro at all this software stuff.
